# Div will not stay in place on page resize and creating a bottom gap in page

Tags: css

I have a basic CSS set up for a chat window. I have spaced it  into 4 sections. The issue is in the `clients` div which is at the bottom right. The div does not stay in place as I scroll and creates a large gap bellow div `bottomPanel`. How could I get the `clients` div in the right position with out causing the page to break? Although It seems to be have normal in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lur6otb4/1/) it is not in my local server.

CSS

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body{
    position:relative;
}

#wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border:1px solid #333;      
}

#upperPanel{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:100px;
}

#chat{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:200px; 
    background:#666;  
    overflow:auto;    
}

#operators{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:200px;
    right:0; 
    background:#999; 
    overflow:auto;   
    height:50%;
}

#bottomPanel{
    height: 100px;
    background:#EEE;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}

#bottomPanel textarea{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
    right:120px; 
    resize: none;
}

#clients{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:200px;
    right:0; 
    background:#FFFFFF; 
    overflow:auto;
    height:50%;
    margin-top:33%;
}

#bottomPanel input[type=submit]{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
     right:10px;
    width:100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="upperPanel">
        <div id="chat">

        </div>
        <div id="operators">
            <center><b>Operators:</b></center>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>Op1:</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Op2:</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Op3:</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
              <div id="clients">
                  <center><b>Clients:</b></center>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>Client1:</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Client2:</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Client3:</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomPanel">
        <textarea>
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is your page supposed to be a single page the full height and width of the view port? If so why not use position fixed for the wrapper?

Comment: @otherDewi correct a single page. Not sure if I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Set margin-bottom:-2000px; for the bottomPanel. It will stick at the bottom of your page, no matter how much you scroll.